# How change the color hamburger icon in runtime android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I reviewed many answers and they all boil down to the use of the method:getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(drawerArrow);
I need to change the color of the real-time standard material hamburger icon. When I use this code:

```
DrawerArrowDrawable drawerArrow = new DrawerArrowDrawable(this);
drawerArrow.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(drawerArrow);
```

the animation stops. How do I fix this? Thank you advance!